# Переопределение шаблона админки Django не работает на хостинге

Tags: django, django-admin

В общем у меня такая структура

```
project
     |manage.py
     |project/
         |myapp/
         |templates/
             |admin/
                  |myapp/
                      |change_form.html
```

в фале html такой код

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block field_sets %}
     {# your modification here #}
{% endblock %}
```

settings

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

на локальном сервере все хорошо
но когда залили на хостинг, изменений нет. В чем проблема ?

Comment: А что у вас в `settings.py` в переменной `TEMPLATES` прописано? Выполняете ли вы команду `./manage.py collectstatic`? Так же можно попробовать вынести `change_form.html` с `myapp ` в `admin`.

Comment: @5c0rp добавил в вопрос настройку TEMPLATES. `collectstatic` делал. В админ в статику? или там где лежат все html в `virtualenv`

Comment: у вас папка `templates` лежит на одном уровне с `manage.py`?

Comment: @5c0rp нет, manage.py на уровень выше, там где  `project`. Добавил в структуру

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пару рабочих вариантов:

1. Вынести папку `templates` на один уровень с `manage.py` и указать в настройках TEMPLATES следующее

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Так у вас все шаблоны будут в одном месте и что бы (в вашем случае) изменить что то в админке нужно поместить новый шаблон в `/templates/admin/change_form.html`. Аналогично будет и с шаблонами для ваших `app` - `/templates/myapp/some_template.html`

2. Оставить настройки как есть и тогда в самой папке `myapp` создать папку `templates`. Далее подойдут примеры с варианта 1.

Comment: спасибо, помагло